# zypper lp command not working on Suse Linux

Tags: linux, cloud, sles, patch-management, zypper

I'm trying to list patches in suse linux GCE using the zypper lp command, but I am getting the following error:

"Medium not attached: plugin:/susecloud?credentials=Basesystem_Module_x86_64&path=/repo/SUSE/Products/SLE-Module-Basesystem/15/x86_64/product/
Abort, retry, ignore? [a/r/i/...? shows all options] (a): "

I used the same command for another suse machine, and it worked, but it doesn't work on this machine and 1 other. Not sure what the problem is. Anyone experienced this before?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue: Suse made some changes to the cloud update infrastructure. You can go here for further details:

https://www.suse.com/support/kb/doc/?id=000019633